# Show an operator is bounded and calculate the norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Show that the operator $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ is bounded and find its norm, where $Tf(t)=\int_0^t e^{-(t-x)}f(x)dx$.

My calculation:\begin{aligned}
\|Tf\|^2&=\int_0^1|\int_0^t e^{-(t-x)}f(x)dx|^2dt\\
&\leq \int_0^1(\int_0^t e^{-(t-x)}dx)(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2dx)dt\\
&=\int_0^1(1-e^{-t})(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2dx)dt\\
&\leq (1-e^{-1})\int_0^1(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2dx)dt\\
&=(1-e^{-1})\|f\|^2
\end{aligned}
Then $\|Tf\|\leq\sqrt{(1-e^{-1})}\|f\|$ and the norm is $\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|=\sqrt{(1-e^{-1})}$.

I don't know whether my calculation is correct. Could someone take a look? Thanks!

Comment: The second line wrong. You did not apply Holder's inequality correctly.  BTW it is much harder to find the exact value of the norm than  to just show that it is less than or equal to some number.

Comment: I applied the Cauchy Schwartz inequality, did I use it correct?

Comment: No, you forgot to square $e^{-(t-x)}$.

Comment: @delta, to find exact value of norm, consider the operator $T^{\ast}T$ and find his eigenvalues. Since this operator compact and self-adjoint, his norm is simply maximum-module-eigenvalue. Then use that $\|T^\ast T\|=\|T\|^2$.

Comment: @thing In here, does the equality $\|T^*\|=\|T\|$ hold?

Comment: Of course, its hold for any bounded linear operator.

Comment: @thing Why did you say the operator $T$ is self-adjoint? I calculated the adjoint of $T$, and concluded that $T^*\not=T$, that is, $T^*g(x)=\int_x^1 e^{-(t-x)}g(t)dt$. Did I compute it wrong?

Comment: I say $T^\ast T$ is self-adjoint and compact.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Cauchy-Schwarz, your second line should be 
$$\int_0^1(\int_0^t e^{-2(t-x)}dx)(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2dx)dt$$

Also, your last line should be an inequality, not an equality, as in $$(1-e^{-1})\int_0^1\left(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2\,dx\right)\,dt
\leq(1-e^{-1})\|f\|^2$$

Last, if it all were correct, we would *only* be able to conclude $\|T\| \leq \sqrt{1-e^{-1}},$ not an equality.

Comment: Since $\int_0^t e^{-2(t-x)}dx=\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2t})$. Could I compute that $\int_0^1(\int_0^t e^{-2(t-x)}dx)(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2dx)dt\leq \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2x}) \int_0^1(\int_0^t|f(x)|^2dx)dt\leq \frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2}) \|f\|^2$, and then $\|T\|\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2})}$?

Comment: You have what I assume to be a typo there ($e^{-2x}$ instead of $e^{-2}$) but otherwise that all works.  I don't know how this will give you $\|T\|$ though.

Comment: I calculated the norm through $\|T\|\leq\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2})}$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you have shown $\|T\|=\sup_{\|f\|=1}\|Tf\|\leq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2})}$.  In fact, we have $\|T\|<\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-e^{-2})}$, so it won't help you find the operator norm.  To do that, you need to start with Holder's inequality or, more specifically, Young's inequality. (maybe there's some way of doing it with CS or another inequality, but I don't see it)